# Mongodb Update opearation takes long time to insert new array filed in the existing collection documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a collection having around 2.5 million documents in it. Now I've to add two array fields in all the records in the collection. But my update operation takes long time to complete. Below is my query

```
db.products.update({
  "code": {
            "$nin": [
              "Tvs",
              "Lg",
              "Roots",
              "Mix",
              "A10",
              "PTPL",
              "Philips",
              "FireFox",
              "Akkade" ]
          }
         },
{
  "$push": {
    "rights": "Read",
    "Acc": "K23424"
  }
},
false,
true)
```

Above update takes around 2 minutes to update the entire collection.Is there any other way to optimize this update query.

**Edit:**

Including model explain plan result

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor code_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 106192,
    "nscannedObjects" : 106192,
    "nscanned" : 106197,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 106192,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 106197,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 829,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 275,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "code" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }, 
                "adfgfgg"
            ], 
            [ 
                "5def354", 
                "akargfdc"
            ], 
            [ 
                "34aka545dc", 
                "akags"
            ], 
            [ 
                "354erak53ag345s", 
                "ci45t45r6rg"
            ], 
            [ 
                "cyuikitryui7ixsg", 
                "gp"
            ], 
            [ 
                "gp", 
                "gslbansgrp"
            ], 
            [ 
                "gsl7878nsgrp", 
                "l7hrgyn"
            ], 
            [ 
                "l678uhn", 
                "l6yup"
            ], 
            [ 
                "lfghrhyhp", 
                "radwaregslbsg"
            ], 
            [ 
                "radwaregslbsg", 
                "radwaregslbsgrs"
            ], 
            [ 
                "radwaregslbsgrs", 
                "radwarers"
            ], 
            [ 
                "rargydwarers", 
                "radwaresg"
            ], 
            [ 
                "radwargyresg", 
                "radwaresgrs"
            ], 
            [ 
                "radwaresgrs", 
                "slr6y6bsf"
            ], 
            [ 
                "slbrtrtsf", 
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "localhost:6789",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 106198,
        "yields" : 829,
        "unyields" : 829,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 106192,
        "needTime" : 5,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 106197,
                "yields" : 829,
                "unyields" : 829,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 106192,
                "needTime" : 5,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ code: 1.0 }",
                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['code']: [MinKey, \"arhtgh10sg\"), (\"a1rgtrg0sg\", \"akadc\"), (\"akadc\", \"akags\"), (\"akags\", \"ctryitrrgyrtgyixsg\"), (\"crtytryityyrixsg\", \"gp\"), (\"gp\", \"gslytyybansgrp\"), (\"gstrytylbansgrp\", \"ln\"), (\"lrytryyn\", \"lyty5typ\"), (\"lty5ty5tp\", \"radwaregtryslbsg\"), (\"radwaregs454t45rgtlbsg\", \"radwaregslbsgrs\"), (\"radwa45654t6regslbsgrs\", \"radware46rs\"), (\"radwrfgarers\", \"rad456waresg\"), (\"r457423adwaresg\", \"radw34aresgrs\"), (\"ra5656dw5rty5aresgrs\", \"slbs6565656f\"), (\"slb66rty5rty5sf\", MaxKey]",
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 106197,
                "children" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Regards,
Roots

Comment: Do you have an index created on the field `"code"`? Try adding [**`.explain()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to the end of your mongo query, mongo will return details about how it goes about fulfilling that query. This will help you understand what indexes are being used and how many documents mongo actually sifts through to generate the result.

Comment: @chridam :  We have index on "code" .but still we are facing query slowness. Is it possible to re write above query in a diffrent way to improve performance

Comment: @chridam:  How do we know my index is used in my query.. What is the parameter from explain() command indicates wheter index has been used or not

Comment: Try running this command `db.products.find({
  "code": {
            "$nin": [
              "Tvs",
              "Lg",
              "Roots",
              "Mix",
              "A10",
              "PTPL",
              "Philips",
              "FireFox",
              "Akkade" ]
          }
         }).explain()`. The results you get from the query will show you which indexes are used and other useful information as explained [**here**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/).

Comment: @chridam  my explain() command shows indexOnly: false.. So this means my index on the code is not used by query?

Comment: Could you [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32946372/edit) your question to include what you have also tried as above and the full document with the [**`explain()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) results?

Comment: @chridam:  I included explain plan for my query.. Please note: I have modify some search filed and server address in the explain plan

Comment: Answering your last question on the meaning of `indexOnly: false`, the key [**`indexOnly`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexOnly) in the explain results returns true when the query is covered by the index indicated in the cursor field. When an index covers a query, MongoDB can both match the query conditions and return the results using only the index because all the fields in the query are part of that index, and all the fields returned in the results set are in the same index. I will shortly provide a solution that I have in mind.

Comment: @Chridam Thank you very much for your time and help. Awaiting for your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the inequality operator **[`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a **[`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** query with an index may perform no better than a **[`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** query that must scan all documents in a collection. Think of it this way, indexes are very useful for finding thing which match, not which don't. For instance, a **[`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** query that returns every document in a collection but one and for each document, the query will first have to look in the index, and then return the document. This is two "look-ups", as opposed to a table
scan, which would only look at each document once. In general, if your query requires more than half of the index to be used, you should re-examine how the query is performed, or resort to a table scan at the very least. So if you need to use **[`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)**, it's often best to make sure that an additional, more selective criterion is part of the query. See also [**Query Selectivity**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/#read-operations-query-selectivity).

You could use the **[Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** as a way of optimising your update by including an additional query that ensures selectivity, in this case the **[`Bulk.find().update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/)** query contains the **`_id`** field which is by default indexed and an equality match on the unique **`_id`** field is highly selective as it can match at most one document. The other key to increasing speed on updates is to note how MongoDB gives a lot of control over how database operations are acknowledged by a server.

The following example initializes a **[`Bulk()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update)** operations builder for the products collection, and adds multi update operations to the list of operations. It uses ordered bulk operations which are stepped through in order (thus the name), halting when there's an error:

```
var bulk = db.products.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0,
    criteria = {
        "code": {
            "$nin": [
              "Tvs",
              "Lg",
              "Roots",
              "Mix",
              "A10",
              "PTPL",
              "Philips",
              "FireFox",
              "Akkade" 
            ]
        }
    };

db.products.find().forEach(function(doc){

    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id, "code": criteria.code }).update({
        "$push": { "rights": "Read", "Acc": "K23424" }
    })}

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up queues
if (counter % 1000 != 0){
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: After using bulk API , the update time was increased .. Previous command took around 20 seconds to complete.But now takes around 70 seconds

Comment: Hmm I must be missing something here, in your question you said it took 2 minutes but here it's now 20 secs? However, I believe the issue is that the inequality operator [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) query with an index may perform no better than a [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) query that must scan all documents in a collection.

Comment: In the production database it is taking 2 mins. I ran your script in testing database with less data. Previously in testing Db it was taking 20 mins. Now It is taking 75 sec.. Is it possible to change $nin with any other operator which supports full index usage

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing an issue like this currently, a good way to decrease the time drastically is to create indexes for your collections.